# Infinite computation of qsort

Tags: c++, quicksort

i am realsing qsort algorithm, according on Korman. But there is infinite computation, when i trying to start it. I suppose, that problem is in partition. My programms reads from file, first number in file-line is counting of numbers to sort, and next go all numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int swap(int &a, int &b);
int sorting(int *array, int &b, int &l);
int partition(int *array ,int &begin, int &last);


int main()
{
    FILE* pFile=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    //fopen("input.txt", "r");
    //fopen("output.txt", "w");
    int n;
    int begin=0;
    fscanf(pFile, "%d", &n);
    int* array=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        fscanf(pFile,"%d", &array[i]);
    int n1=n-1;
    sorting(array, begin, n1);
    printf("JJJJ");
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    fclose(pFile);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

int sorting(int* array, int &b, int &l)
{
    int pivot,pivot1;
    if(b<l)
    {
        pivot=partition(array, b, l);
        printf("MAXMAX321");
        int a=pivot-1;
        sorting(array, b, a);
        printf("MAXMAX123");
        pivot1=pivot+1;
        sorting(array, pivot1, l);
        printf("MAXMAX");
    }
    return 0;
}

int partition(int* array, int &b, int &l)
{
    int x=array[b];
    int i=b;
    int j=l;
    while(true)
    {
        while(array[j]>x){
            printf("AHAH");
            --j;
        }
        while(array[i]<x){
            printf("AZAZA");
            ++i;
        }
        if(i<j)
            swap(array[i],array[j]);
        else
            return j; 

    }
}

int swap(int &x, int &y)
{
    x=x+y;
    y=x-y;
    x=x-y;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Except for the use of references, this is pure C code.

Answer (score 1):

This part is very dangerous code:

```
while(true)
{
    while(array[j]>x){
        printf("AHAH");
        --j;
    }
    while(array[i]<x){
        printf("AZAZA");
        ++i;
    }
    if(i<j)
        swap(array[i],array[j]);
    else
        return j; 

}
```

1. Avoid `while (true)` as much as possible, except on very special case you should have a clear condition stated in the loop. Here it is the one that leads to `return. It will clarify the goal of the loop.
2. When testing array value like `while(array[i]<x)` compare `i` to the array size before ! You're never sure that you condition will always be met in the array, ensure you have a safety belt.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what you are doing in function partition but doing it like this should work:

```
int partition(int* array, int &b, int &l)
{
    int pivot_index = l;//You can take here everything between b and l
    //swap(array[l], array[pivot_index]); decomment this if your pivot is between b and l
    int current_pos = b;
    for(int i = b;i < l - 1; ++i)
        if(array[i] <= array[pivot_index])
            swap(array[i], array[current_pos++]);
    swap(array[l], array[current_pos]);
    return current_pos;
}
```

Comment: It is not working, there is no errors, but the answer is wrong

Comment: There should be <= not <. changed.. I am still looking maybe there is something more